# How do I debug a wordpress white screen when I go to wp-admin/admin-post.php

Tags: php, wordpress, cloudflare

How do I debug a WordPress white screen when I go to wp-admin/admin-post.php

I have disabled every plugin and tried changing the theme, and it still gives me a blank page.  Latest version of WordPress.

I'm using Cloudflare (free) for nameservers/cdn, etc...

Any ideas why this would happen?

I've var_dumped the last error and just comes back with null.

I noticed this issue when a plugin asks me to clear this cache and I try clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

In `wp-config.php` (in WP root folder) enable debugging:

```
   define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
   define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); // add this line for log output
```

Log is usually written to file `debug.log` in `wp-content`.

What is the output? You can also check the error log of your web server, location depends on individual setup. In case no actual error is logged in either of the logs, might be an issue with the cloudflare setup itself.